# Django multiple values in single form field

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I add multiple values in a single form field just like the image below

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry

Comment: Can I do this with MultiValueField?

Answer (score 0):

I found bootstrap tag input to be able to do multi value field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Bootstrap library
https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/